# setting lookup values for the url paramater in routes.maproute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

Is there an easy way to define lookup values in your route.maproute?

example route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
              name: "example route", 
               url: "product/{subcat}", 
          defaults: new { controller = "Redirect", action = "ProcessPage"}
      );
```

Where: {subcat}  can only be the following values: subcat1, subcat2, subcat3

I'm trying to write redirects from an old site to a new site (can't use IIS), the old site does not have consistent urls and some of them fall into patterns of my new site.  I would like to avoid writing a route for every single redirect.

Comment: [Creating custom route constraints in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/3/creating_custom_route_constraints_in_asp_net_mvc) blog will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to constrain your route values:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "example route", 
    url: "product/{subcat}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Redirect", action = "ProcessPage"},
    constraints: new { subcat = @"^subcat\d*$ }
);
```

I've assumed here that the constraint is "subcat" appended with an integer (that's the best I can extract from your question) - modify this to meet your requirements. If you need an explicit set of values, you can just use the regex OR operator with your list of accepted strings:

```
@"^subcat1|subcat2|subcat3$"
```

Comment: The list of exact strings was what I was looking for.  Thank you so much!